# How to capture context? polling/events

Tags: android, cordova

How do apps like tasker capture context. Suppose I want to capture context that when wifi is switched on do something. Is it possible to attach a callback for isWifiEnabled()? or execute a handler when wifi gets enabled without polling. An example code or link to an example code to perform some action when wifi is enabled would be nice. There is `isWifiEnabled()` function in the api but I am not sure how to use this using Intents.

Answer (score 2):

They're listening for the system message that is broardcast when these event take place.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

When the WiFi is turned on or off there is a broadcast of an Intent with the action set to [WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION). If you create a [`<receiver>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html) with an [`<intent-filter>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) set to catch it, your app will be notified.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am new to android development. Can you refer some example to perform what I described in the updated question.